# Target group isn't configured to receive traffic from the load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-vpc

I've a task to realize the structure like at picture and add the missing components.
[Task pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIZw6.jpg)

As far as I can understand I need to do the vollowing:

1. Create VPC
2. Create 2 public subnets and 2 private subnets
3. Create internet gateway and 2 nat gateways and different AZ
4. Create route from public subnets to internet to use internet gateway
5. Create route from private subnets to internet to use nat gateways
6. Create ACL rule for 80 port
7. Create 2 instances at each AZ
8. Add them to target group
9. Create LB and attach the target group to them.

After making all this operations, I can't access LB via dns name. I've an error: target group isn't configured to receive traffic from the LB. Please advice, what did I forget. Thanks. The copy of archive U can find by following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nhxafSX0uaDTobRe9vvmfdkq88ubNqft/view?usp=sharing)

**Main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}


resource "aws_instance" "host1" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami = data.aws_ami.latest_ubuntu.id
  user_data = base64encode("${file("install_nginx.sh")}")
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.allow_http_https.id]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.host1-private.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Host1"
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "host2" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami = data.aws_ami.latest_ubuntu.id
  user_data = base64encode("${file("install_nginx.sh")}")
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.allow_http_https.id]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.host2-private.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Host2"
  }
}
```

**app_lb.tf**

```
resource "aws_lb" "web" {
  name               = "mainLB"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
//  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.host1-public.id, aws_subnet.host2-public.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "Main LB"
  }
}

#---------------------------------------------

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.web.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.http.arn
  }
}



#---------------------------------------------
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "http" {
  name = "http-tg"
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  target_type = "instance"
 }

#----------------------------------------------
  resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "host1" {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.http.arn
    target_id        = aws_instance.host1.id
    port             = 80
  }

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "host2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.http.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.host2.id
  port             = 80
}
```

**network.tf**

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}


#-----------------------------------------------------
resource "aws_subnet" "host1-private" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "Private_Subnet_Host1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "host1-public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.11.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "Public_Subnet_Host1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "host2-private" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.20.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  tags = {
    Name = "Private_Subnet_Host2"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "host2-public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.21.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "Public_Subnet_Host2"
  }
}
```

**routing.tf**

```
resource "aws_route_table" "web" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Net rules"
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table" "nat-a" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

    route {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw_host1.id
    }


  tags = {
    Name = "Nat-a rules"
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table" "nat-b" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id


  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw_host2.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Nat-b rules"
  }
}




resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.host1-private.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.nat-a.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.host2-private.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.nat-b.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "c" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.host1-public.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.web.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "d" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.host2-public.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.web.id
}
```

**gateways.tf**

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

#------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_eip" "lb-host1" {
  vpc      = true
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb-host2" {
  vpc      = true
}

#------------------------------------------------------
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw_host1" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb-host1.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.host1-private.id

  tags = {
    Name = "gw NAT host1"
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw_host2" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb-host2.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.host2-private.id

  tags = {
    Name = "gw NAT host2"
  }
}
```

**acl**

```
resource "aws_default_network_acl" "main" {
  default_network_acl_id = aws_vpc.main.default_network_acl_id

  ingress {
    protocol   = "tcp"
    rule_no    = 101
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 443
    to_port    = 443
  }

  ingress {
    protocol   = "tcp"
    rule_no    = 102
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 80
    to_port    = 80
  }

  egress {
    protocol   = "tcp"
    rule_no    = 103
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 80
    to_port    = 80
  }

  egress {
    protocol   = "tcp"
    rule_no    = 104
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 443
    to_port    = 443
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow http & https traffic"
  }
}



resource "aws_security_group" "allow_http_https" {
  name = "Dynamic Security Group"
  description = "Allow http & https inbound traffic"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.sg_ports
    content {
      from_port = ingress.value
      to_port = ingress.value
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = [
        "0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [
      "0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_http_https"
  }
}
```

data.tf

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {

}

data "aws_ami" "latest_ubuntu" {
  owners = [
    "099720109477"]
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = [
      "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "default" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error logs?

Comment: Can you see on LB Target group that your EC2 Instances are registered and Healthy ?

Comment: Your aws_default_network_acl and NATs are incorrect. `var.sg_ports` is not shown.

Comment: I also noticed that all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not onlly a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances of your issues being actually answered.